# Workflow Logic with two lists

Tags: list, workflow

Here's what I've got:

- I've got a LIST called STAFF, that has Staff names and emails
- I've got a LIST called CONTACT STAFF that is fed from a FORM whenever someone needs to contact someone on the STAFF list.  When they click NEW, the form pops up.  The person requesting help from the staff on the list chooses LOCATION (from a drop down list), and writes whatever message they want in in a text field below.

Both of these lists have these staff (and their emails) listed in order of LOCATION (a field that exists in both lists)

The STAFF list has a separate field (SUPERVISOR EMAIL), again, appropriate to LOCATION.

Still with me? I'm glad you are!

I'm trying to create a workflow that sends an EMAIL to the appropriate STAFF and SUPERVISOR whenever someone creates a new record in the CONTACT STAFF list, based on the LOCATION chosen from the ddl.

Because of the two separate lists, I'm having a bit of problem trying to come up with the right workflow that will make this happen.  Any ideas?

Comment: so far i just know, each workflow is only able to be triggered by one list only.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

- Create associated workflow on the CONTACT STAFF list to run when a new
  item is created
- Create two workflow variables StaffEmail & SupervisorEmail (String type)
- Set those variable values using  `set workflow variable action` from the first list STAFF, and get the
  required Item from the STAFF list by using the Location (Location in the STAFF = Location in CONTACT STAFF)
- send email using the created variables in the `TO` field and set their return type as email address.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this one both in SP Dev and Nintex Workflows.  Alas, I was not able to make it work.  Admittedly, I did have some difficulty in creating what the variables pointed to.